# Angular unit test, mock property of provider

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm really new to unit testing and especially with Angular. I have a problem, in my `TestBed.configureTestingModule` I have provider which has private getter and this getter relies on an custom generic service which gets the value from a file. How can I mock this value without having to rely on the custom service which searches for a specific file? Lets say the getter is `url`. I've tried with

```
{
   provide: SomeService, useValue: {
     url: 'www.test.com'
   }
},
```

But then I get error in my component `this.someService.SomeFunction is not a function`, what am I missing?

Comment: Create a mock class with same structure but can be partial, use an instance of it as useValue. `provide: SomeService, useValue: mockSomeService`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming with provider you mean a Service, an elegant way would be to use the jasmine tool [spyOnProperty](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.2/global.html#spyOnProperty).

Something like this where you have a private getter

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class TestService {
    
      private _url: string = 'www.random.com';
    
      constructor() { }
    
      private get url(): string {
        return this._url;
      }
    }
```

and test it like this

```js
    describe('TestService', () => {
    
      let testService: TestService;
    
      beforeEach(() => {
    
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ ],
            providers: [ TestService ]
        });
    
        testService = TestBed.get(TestService);
        
      });

      it('tests getter with property Spy', () => {
        expect(testService.url).toEqual('www.random.com');

        const urlSpy = spyOnProperty(testService, 'url', 'get').and.returnValue('www.happy.com');

        expect(testService.url).toEqual('www.happy.com');

      });
    });
```

Comment: This is an old version of jasmine, now it's missing from it's API. What is the replacement

Comment: @IamStalker it’s not missing, spyOnProperty still being used in 3.5 according the [docs](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/global.html#spyOnProperty).